# can't execute shell script on centos 8

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, sh

I am running sh script from docker node:17-alpine.

I got the error SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token at # wait-for-maria.sh.

May I know how to run script on docker?

```
#!/bin/sh
# wait-for-maria.sh

set -e

host="$1"
shift

until PGPASSWORD=$MARIA_PASSWORD psql -h "$host" -U "root" -c '\q'; do
  >&2 echo "Maria is unavailable - sleeping"
  sleep 1
done

>&2 echo "Maria is up - executing command"
exec "$@"
```

docker compose

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  db:
    container_name: myimage-db
    image: asia.gcr.io/imagecontainer/myimage/db
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./db/data/:/var/lib/mariadb/data
    environment:
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: xxx
      MARIADB_DATABASE: mydb
    expose:
      - 3306
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    networks:
      - gita

  data_api:
    container_name: myimage-data-api
    image: asia.gcr.io/imagecontainer/myimage/data-api
    expose:
      - 4000
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    command: ["./wait-for-maria.sh", "db:3306", "--", "python", 
"app.py"]

    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: mysql://root:xxx@db:3306/mydb
      ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET: xxx
      REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET: xx
    networks:
      - gita


networks:
  gita:
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:17 AS BUILD_IMAGE
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ["package.json", "yarn.lock", "tsconfig.json", "wait-for- 
maria.sh", "./"]
COPY ["./prisma/schema.prisma", "./prisma/"]
RUN chmod +x ./wait-for-maria.sh
RUN yarn install --no-cache bash
RUN yarn --frozen-lockfile
RUN yarn prisma generate
COPY . .
RUN yarn build
#RUN yarn install --production
RUN yarn autoclean --force

FROM node:17-alpine
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY --from=BUILD_IMAGE /usr/src/app/dist ./dist
COPY --from=BUILD_IMAGE /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=BUILD_IMAGE /usr/src/app/prisma ./prisma
COPY --from=BUILD_IMAGE /usr/src/app/package*.json ./
COPY --from=BUILD_IMAGE /usr/src/app/wait-for-maria.sh ./

EXPOSE 4000
#CMD [ "node", "dist/server.js" ]
CMD [  "npm", "run", "start:migrate:prod" ]
```

Comment: Make sure you have Unix style line endings (CR) and not Windows style (CRLF) in your script file.

Comment: This `SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` looks like an error from javascript so it may have nothing to do with `sh` script but rather the way you are executing the script in node.js. Can you show the node.js code?

Comment: @Molda Actually , I run it from docker-compose file that's update in my main post. command: ["./wait-for-maria.sh", "db:3306", "--", "python", "app.py"]

Comment: @HansKilian Yes, I already check it and it is correct format.

Comment: Can you show the full error message from the log?

Answer (score 0):

I use docker-compose-wait as follow.

ADD https://github.com/ufoscout/docker-compose-wait/releases/download/2.5.0/wait /wait
RUN chmod +x /wait
CMD /wait && yarn start:migrate:prod